# Which apps belong to Odoo 13 Enterprise could support to connect with biometric machine with brand: NIDEKA?

Tags: import, module, odoo

I'm now using the biometric machine with brand: NIDEKA - UTF630.

And I would like to connect Attendance module of Odoo 13 Enterprise with that machine to auto get attendance data file from the machine and auto import into attendance module.

So which apps could support about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this App [Click Here](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/13.0/hr_zk_attendance/). It will be work for you.

Thanks